# Información para realizar un menu accesible

Tags: html, css, accesibilidad

Estoy realizando una web en Wordpress y necesito que se accesible por teclado pero no lo consigo ya que solo accedo al primer nivel y se salta los segundos.

Os adjunto como lo tengo realizado. Para ser sincero estoy poniendome al dia en css y no estoy al dia ya que llevaba tiempo sin hacerlo.

He intentado relazarlo de varias formas pero no consigo implementarlo.

Mi plantilla de wordpress no lo trae y he de insertalo mediante HTML Blocks

Ruego me informeis de como poder realizarlo y agradezco vuestro aporte.

Un saludo

```css
nav ul, nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav > ul {
  
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}

nav > ul > li {
  line-height:40px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:0 10px;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:40px;
  background:#aaa;
  display:none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  width:150px;
  padding:0 10px;
}

li:focus ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <a href="#">NAVAL</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ACOPLAMIENTOS TUBERIAS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ACOPLAMIENTOS TUBERIAS ECO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ACOPLAMIENTOS CONTRAINCENDIOS</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">EXPANSIONES METÁLICAS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">COMPENSADORES DE GOMA</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">VALVULAS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">INSTRUMENTACIÓN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <a href="#">INDUSTRIAL</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">INSTRUMENTACIÓN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CATALOGOS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CERTIFICADOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TIENDA</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```